# oncomplete attribute of h:commandLink not invoked

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, commandlink

We are migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.2.6 along with RichFaces 4.5.2. Facing issues with the `oncomplete` not getting called. The JS function during `onclick` gets called, but JS in `oncomplete` does not get called. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

```
<h:commandLink ... onclick="ed();" oncomplete="cEd(#{rowIndex});">
```

Comment: we are facing this issue with h:commandlink. actionlistener is getting called in java. but oncomplete doesn't get triggered.is there a right way of using oncomplete with h:commandlink?

Comment: The code we are using now:<h:commandLink id="e" actionListener="#{controller.selectItem}" value="#{msg.action_edit}"
 render="#{parentId}:item_entry_form" eventsQueue="i"
 ignoreDupResponses="true" immediate="true" ajaxSingle="true"
 onclick="ed();" oncomplete="cEd(#{rowIndex});">
 <f:param name="objectId" value="#{rowIndex}" />
 <f:param name="conversationId" value="#{conversation.id}" />
</h:commandLink>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[There is indeed no such attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/commandLink.html) in `<h:commandLink>`. You're most likely confusing with `<a4j:commandLink>` which [does have that attribute](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.5.X/4.5.2.Final/vdldoc/a4j/commandLink.html).

You've basically 2 options:

1. Just replace `<h:commandLink>` by `<a4j:commandLink>`.

   ```
   <a4j:commandLink ... oncomplete="oncompleteFunction()" />
   ```
2. Nest a `<f:ajax>` with an event handler inside `<h:commandLink>`.

   ```
   <h:commandLink ...>
       <f:ajax onevent="oneventFunction" /><!-- No parenthesis! -->
   </h:commandLink>
   ```

   ```
   function oneventFunction(data) {
       if (data.status === "success") {
           oncompleteFunction();
       }
   }
   ```

Hint for the future: just read the tag documentation. Links are in 1st paragraph.

Comment: we actually tried using f:ajax and a4j:commandlink as well.It works fine for the first time. We faced a unique issue of the link itself not working the second time when we do this.  actionlistener only doesn't get called the secondtime when we use a4j:commandlink or f:ajax

Comment: That's a different problem which is unrelated to the current question. That problem has already been asked and answered long before.

Comment: ok..Agreed. can you share your inputs here or should I post as a new question pls? We did try searching and could find posts where  issue of first click not working is only discussed.

Comment: my situation is inverse to above one. First click only works fine. not the second and further.hope my query is right.

Comment: That will happen if the first click did not update the form afterwards.

Comment: Tried to update the form using render="@form" and also render="actualformname" in a4j:commandlink. Doesn't work..suspected this could be an issue of conditionally rendering the form and removed the "rendered" attribute of the form. still, no results :(

Comment: Sounds like candidate for a new question ([make sure you prepare a good MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)).