# h:commandButton with oncomplete function and download a file

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, commandbutton

I have a little problem because i need to download a file (and for that i only can with h:commandButton) but i needed the oncomplete function (that only works with a4j:commandButton) to appear a Running Status.
The sample of the code is this:

```
 <h:commandButton
        id="downloadReportButton"
        action="#{reportingBean.createAndDonwloadFile()}"               
 />
```

I already try to do  it like in this response by BalusC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31267418/1777424 but the problem is because of Ajax requests are not perform.

```
<h:commandButton
        id="downloadReportButton"
        action="#{reportingBean.createAndDonwloadFile()}"/>
        <f:ajax onevent="oneventFunction" />
 </h:commandLink>

function oneventFunction(data) {
    if (data.status === "success") {
        oncompleteFunction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to resolve this.
First is needed to have a **a4j:commandButton** just to have the click button with ajax requests. In this part the file will be created.

```
<a4j:commandButton
    id="createFileButton"
    onclick="showLoading();"
    action="#{reportingBean.createFile()}"
    oncomplete="hideLoading(); #rich:element('downloadFileButton')}.click();"
/>
```

This a4j:commandButton will in oncomplete click on **downloadFileButton** button that will download the file.
Then is necessary to have a h:commandButton to download the file that have been created.

```
<h:commandButton
    id="downloadFileButton"
    action="#{reportingBean.downloadFile()}"
    style="display:none"
/>
```

This button will be hidden (**style="display:none"**) because is only to trigger the download of the file.